# What could be the reasons in big accuracy difference between evaluation and test sets?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, r-caret

I have a dataset with 198 observations and 122 features, and two classes which are somewhat balanced (54% for the positive class).

My framework uses a 10-fold cross validation (x10) to choose the model parameters (kernelPLS), and leave-one-out for the test set. Specifically, for each observation, I train the model using 197 observations in a 10-fold CV (repeated 10 times), and used the final, combined model to predict the label of the left out observation.

I'm currently getting very good accuracy using my train/validation set (95% with .05 SD), which is taken over all 100 folds. However, my accuracy in the test set (LOOCV) is only 64%. Any ideas?

I'd think the multi-folds cross-validation would take care of potential overfitting?

Thanks!

Comment: So when you say you "used the final, combined model", what do you mean exactly? You train the model on all training data (which was split into train and validation set during cross_validation)?? CV is mostly used on whole data to check for overfitting and take average of all scores. Its possible that your test set contains some samples which are not correctly recognized by the model. Can you take any other set as test and then do the whole process with the new train and then compare the results?

Comment: Also, without knowing the actual model (like decisiontree, logisticRegression, etc...) and actual code, and also the knowledge of data, its very hard to say. Anyways as this question is not about programming per se, so its off-topic here.Please post this on https://stats.stackexchange.com with relevant details as mentioned above.

Comment: Vivek, thanks for the comment. You pointed out something that might be the crux of the problem. I was under the impression that the combined model was averaging coefficients over all CV models, but it actually refits the model with the selected hyperparameters during CV over the entire training data. In my case, as the number of PLS components was the only parameter chosen during CV, it was fitting that chosen model with n-1 samples, and then predicting the left-out sample. Now that I understand it better, I'm not too surprised by the overfitting. Also, thanks for pointing out the other site!